# проблема с массивом

Tags: php, массивы

```
$getuser2['User'] = array($arUser['firstname'], $arUser["lastname"], '55555555', '552925049', $arUser["email"], ['City', 'Street 11']);

echo json_encode($getuser2);
```

как добавить в массив вот то что выделено красным на изображении?
[image: красном текстом выделенное, нужно добавить в массив]

Comment: вот так - ` 
$getuser2['Email'] = Array("1", "Email not found");` или уточняйте задачу.

Comment: @KoVadim, а где `"Error"`?

Comment: там такое мелкое красное, что я прочитал Email вместо Error `$getuser2['Error'] = Array("1", "Email not found");`

Comment: Нет не правильно поняли, @KoVadim, у меня сейчас так выводит `{"User":["we3wewe","wewewe","55555555","552925049","mephis_top_heles@mail.ru",["City","Street 11"]]}` а мне нужно вот так `{"User":["we3wewe","wewewe","55555555","552925049","mephis_top_heles@mail.ru",["City","Street 11"]], "Error":["1", "Email not found"]}`

Comment: тогда расписывайте детальнее. Телепаты в отпуске.

Comment: Напряг телепатов. Надо так
`$getuser2['User'] = array($arUser['firstname'], $arUser["lastname"], '55555555', '552925049', $arUser["email"], ['City', 'Street 11']);
$getuser2['Error'] = array("1", "Email not found");
echo json_encode($getuser2);`

Comment: @KoVadim, большое спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

```
$getuser2['Error'] = array("1", "Email not found");
```

=) скопировал из комментария, хах

Comment: а где увидели `Email`? :)